# How to Place a variable in pyspark groupby agg query

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I have query in which i want to place the variable data into the group by query

i Tried like this but it not working

```
dd2=(dd1.groupBy("hours").agg({'%s':'%s'})%(columnname1,input1))
```

In the columnname1 contain 'total' and input1 contain what kind of aggregation is required like mean or stddev.
i want this query to be dynamic.

Comment: not sure what you mean exactly by dynamic, but I think what you are looking for would be more simply `dd1.groupBy("hours").agg({columnname1:input1})`?

Comment: `dd2=(dd1.groupBy("hours").agg({'{}'.format(columnname1):'%{}'.format(input1)})`

Comment: @Ben.T Maybe his variables are variable. But who knows.

Comment: actually i want to make it dynamic..like what ever the user request such as mean or standard deviation. it should place in the **agg**  function. @Ben.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
dd2=(dd1.groupBy("hours").agg({'{}'.format(columnname1):'{}'.format(input1)}))
```